# How to make image appear inline with telerik radcombobox

Tags: css, telerik

I am trying to make image appear to immediate right of combobox, but it drops down below it for some reason. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Time" DataValueField="ID"  NoWrap="true" Width="40%" CausesValidation="false"> 
       </telerik:RadComboBox>

<span style="display:inline" class="requiredTimeKeeper"><asp:Image CssClass="inline" id="Image1" ImageUrl="../../images/requiredfield.gif" runat="server"></asp:Image>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the styles for the telerik combo box.
You need both of the elements to have have be display `inline` or `inline-block`

Another option is to give the image absolute positioning, and align it with respect to a relatively positioned parent element. That way you'll be able to fine-tune its position.

Something like this:

```css
.combo {
  position: relative;
}

.requiredTimeKeeper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="combo">
  <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Time" DataValueField="ID" NoWrap="true" Width="40%" CausesValidation="false">
  </telerik:RadComboBox>

  <div class="requiredTimeKeeper">
    <asp:Image CssClass="inline" id="Image1" ImageUrl="../../images/requiredfield.gif" runat="server"></asp:Image>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the boostrap classes: `row` , `col-6` and `col-1` to leave everything in one line, `no-gutters` will help you remove unnecessary `row` padding

```
    <div class="row no-gutters">
      <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddl" class="col-6" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="Time" DataValueField="ID"  NoWrap="true" Width="40%" CausesValidation="false"> 
           </telerik:RadComboBox>

      <span style="display:inline" class="col-1 requiredTimeKeeper"><asp:Image CssClass="inline" id="Image1" ImageUrl="../../images/requiredfield.gif" runat="server"></asp:Image></span>
   </div>
```

> You can adjust the `col-X` depending on the width you are looking for,
>   you have available from `col-1` to `col-12`